Как при превышении индексом длины списка запустить проход по списку заново?
Делаю программу на python, и возникла проблема. Есть список, например:
mylist = ['a', 'b']

, и, если индекс списка больше длины самого списка, то он должен обойти список ещё раз а не вывести ошибку. например:
mylist = ['a', 'b']
print(mylist[3])

Как сделать такое в python?

Очевидно, уменьшить индекс до допустимого диапазона

"если индекс списка больше длинны самого списка то он должен обойти список ещё раз" — что вы под этим имеете в виду? Что должно вывести: "a, b, a"?

Для этого нужно сделать так, чтобы index был меньше длины списка. Это делается взятием остатка.
mylist = ['a', 'b']
index = input('Индекс')
try:
    index = int(index)
except:
    print('Вы ввели не число!')
else:
    print(mylist[index % len(mylist)])


Решение работает с нулевым и с отрицательным index, поэтому требование чтобы index был больше 0 излишне, а вот обработать ошибку, если будет введено не целое число, не помешает
